# How can I access django allauth custom filed

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'd like to save and access custom field of allauth. After I save the form and try to access the data but it's empty.
    {{ user.school }}
I only add forms.py. Do I need to add on models.py too?

-> I change the models but still I can't access the school filed ㅜㅜ)

forms.py
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from django import forms

```
SCHOOL = (
    ('', 'Select your school...'),
    ('ucla.edu', 'UCLA'),
    ('berkeley.edu', 'Berkeley'),
)

class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    school = forms.ChoiceField(choices=SCHOOL, required=True)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.school = self.cleaned_data['school']
        user.save()

models.py
    class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        school = models.CharField(max_length=128)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to extend the user model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 0):

yes.

I would extend the django user model and

```
profile = user.profile
profile.school = self.cleaned_data['school']
profile.save(update_fields=['school'])
```

Comment: Hi @doniyor, when I change the forms.py is shown error 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'. Any help what i missed?

Comment: @MrKarl you need to extend user model by creating new userprofile model with onetoone relation. more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model